# Exporing Dataset to CDF hangs (Mathematica 11.0.0 Linux 64 bit)

Tags: bugs, export, dataset, cdf-format

I want to export a `TabView` to a `CDF`. Some of its tabs have `Dataset`.

```
Block[{content},
  content = TabView[{a -> Dataset[{1, 2}]}];
  Export["file.cdf", content];
  Print[content];
]
```

This above works, Surprisingly If I remove the `Print[content]` It hangs and never return.

```
Block[{content},
  content = TabView[{a -> Dataset[{1, 2}]}];
  Export["file.cdf", content];
]
```

How can I Export `Dataset` to a CDF ? is there any workaround ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using _Mathematica_ 11.1.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Mine is 11.0.0 Linux 64 bit

Comment: Try `CDFDeploy["file.cdf", content, Method -> "Standalone"]`, maybe this will change something.

Comment: INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: Kernels|c|7037
Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research.

Comment: @NeelBasu so, did you report?

Comment: Nope. I will verify the same in Windows Mathematica 11.0.0 version

Comment: I don't have 11.0.0 handy, but I was unable to reproduce the problem with either 11.0.1 or 10.4.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce in windows 10 using Mathematica 11.0.0. If you have a Linux 64 bit with Mathematica 11.0.0 can you validate ?